# Merge Unity 3D scene with Git

Tags: git, version-control, unity-game-engine, merge

I'm trying to implement a Git for a game project of mine. For scripts, it would work well because they are already in text. But what about scene files? They are binary files so merging them will be quite hard. What if I put a game object in the scene and another co-worker put another in the same scene? How would we merge our scenes? Or should we always export / import it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should merge them manually, and just "add" the latest version of the file. A better workflow would be to only let one person at the time change a certain scene.

Comment: It arguably makes little sense for concurrent edits of anything visual whether it is WinForms; XAML; .PNG; or PSD.  One suggestion made by an established Unity game team who gave a Unity talk, was to not put anything in the scene via the designer at all but rather **instantiate everything via pre-fabs using code at runtime**.

Comment: @MickyDuncan: So, in that case, what about the level design? Making a level from, say, an XML file is not as intuitive as making it via the editor.

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra You shouldn't be treating Unity3D as a _level designer_.  Unity have said that in their talks.  Artists generally won't use Unity, they use other tools - licensing being one reason why.  Unity should be used to load the level at runtime.  The same applies for using Unity3D for model design, that's why there are tools like Blender, 3ds etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally holding binary objects in 'source' repository is controversial idea. However recently some specialized tools have appeared http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UniMerge ... so they can be bought or written from scratch.

Comment: Well, two good suggestions at the same time. I wish I can accept both of the answers. But your answer is better IMHO. Thanks.

Comment: _"Generally holding binary objects in 'source' repository is controversial idea"_ - that's arguably too broad.  Binaries produced during _compilation_ - _yes_;  binaries required for the project to be _built_ - _no_.  e.g. In my web project we add **.PNG**s to SCM because they are required for compilation; deployment; and use by the rest of the team.  Similarly we add _audio_; _video_ and other media for Unity.  What may differ is that you have two different repos; one for source code and one for assets as outlined by one of the dev teams during a Unity Talk video

Answer (score 8):

You can save scene files in text mode: `Edit->Project Settings->Editor->Asset Serialization: Force Text`

This way scenes are saved as `Yaml` file, for more details on the format, have a look at the [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/YAMLSceneExample.html).

Despite I sometimes merge scene by hand, it's not a trivial operation, and you must be very careful (git automerge isn't able to merge them properly in 99% of the case).

Comment: Well, two good suggestions at the same time. I wish I can accept both of the answers. Thanks.

Comment: Force Text definitely helps things along. Unity also arbitrarily re-orders your scenes, so a tool like Scene Merge or this guy's sorter also help avoid conflicts in the first place.

Scene Merge: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5412
sorter: http://forums.playstaxel.com/threads/unity-and-git.228/

Comment: @scone - The problem with _Scene Merge_ is that it creates a SCM within a SCM by forcing you to perform a non-Git snapshot via **Create Snapshot** inside Unity.  What happens if I forget to do so?

Comment: It's true. It's far from perfect.  Unity also has a YAML merge tool that ships with current versions.

Comment: @scone - for us the YAML merge tool seems to always fail and fall back on the manual diff tool.

Comment: @scone Is that script available anywhere else perchance, assuming using it is still necessary? Playstaxel requires registration before even viewing a post, it seems

Comment: @koyae it's been a while since I posted that link but I'm pretty sure the ordering issue has been fixed in newer versions of Unity

Comment: Because `.unity` scene and `.prefab` files can contain long lines, Git will sometimes assume they're binary even after you've set them to save as text. You can fix this by creating a `.gitattributes` file in the project root and adding the text `*.unity diff` and `*.prefab diff` on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your team can manage to work on the same Unity scene file and merge it rather smoothly using Git.

1. Make all GameObjects in your scene prefabs. That way, they can each be edited individually.
2. Ignore the scene file from your .gitignore file.
3. Whenever you're making changes in your scene, make sure to apply your changes to your prefabs.

This way, whenever you pull your colleagues' repos, you're not pulling their scene but rather just their prefabs in their scene. So your scene will reconstruct itself with all the latest changes in the prefabs from all your team resulting in a smooth-ish merge.

If you structure your scene well enough, I think this system will work.